# Как определить текущее время (секунды) в формате int в Android?

Tags: java, android, время

Нужно определить, сколько секунд прошло с 00:00. То есть взять значение часов, умножить на 3600 и добавить умноженные на 60 минуты. Но как получить значение часов и минут? Или есть другой более легкий способ?

Comment: Calendar.getInstance()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int hour = date.getHours();
int min = date.getMinutes();
int sec = date.getSeconds();
int hourS = hour * 3600;
int minS = min * 60;

public int output = hourS + minS + sec;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Текущая дата и время в Java**
Получить текущую дату и время в Java достаточно не трудно. Вы можете использовать простой объект date вместе с методом toString(), чтобы вывести текущую дату и время следующим образом:

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Test {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      // Инициализация объекта date
      Date date = new Date();

      // Вывод текущей даты и времени с использованием toString()
      System.out.println(date.toString());
   }
}
```

Получим следующий результат:

```
Sun Nov 13 00:14:19 FET 2016
```

**Сравнение дат**
Существуют три способа в Java сравнить даты:

Можно использовать функцию getTime(), чтобы получить количество миллисекунд, прошедших с момента полуночи 1 января 1970, для обоих объектов, а затем сравнить эти два значения.

Вы можете использовать методы before(), after() и equals(). Поскольку 12 число месяца раньше 18 числа, например, new Date(99, 2, 12).before(new Date (99, 2, 18)) возвращает значение true.

Можно использовать метод compareTo(), который определяется сопоставимым интерфейсом и реализуется по дате.

**Разница дат в Java**
измерить точку во времени в миллисекундах.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      try {
         long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
         System.out.println(new Date() + "\n");
         
         Thread.sleep(10000);
         System.out.println(new Date() + "\n");
         
         long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
         long diff = end - start;
         System.out.println("Разница между датами: " + diff + " миллисекунд");
      }catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Получили исключение!");
      }
   }
}
```

Получим следующий результат:

Sun Nov 13 03:22:10 FET 2016

Sun Nov 13 03:22:20 FET 2016

Разница между датами: 10081 миллисекунд

Comment: Спасибо, но это не то. Мне нужно не date, а именно int значение секунд, которые прошли с 00:00 сегодняшнего дня. System.currentTimeMillis(); даёт число с 1970 годов, а мне нужно с текущего

Comment: ну тогда почитайте про классы для работы с датой  в java, подберите наиболее подходящий и про приведение типов к int